# Stake Pool Pledge: Must the pledge amount be part of the active stake? Is Live stake okay?

Tags: stake-pool, pledge

I understand the pledge must be met by the stake pool owners. My question is basically if ada is added it takes 2 epochs to become active stake.

Can I increase the pledge amount immediately after the ada is added to the owner wallet or should I wait 2 epochs until the amount is active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I increase the pledge amount immediately after the ada is added to
> the owner wallet -

Yes.

> or should I wait 2 epochs until the amount is active?

No.